# pyspark equivalent of the flag "isLocal" from Scala API

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

Scala has a flag `isLocal`. If this is `true` then we know that Spark is running in local mode, else it is running on a cluster. Is there any pyspark alternative to this? Or do we simply check `sc.master`?

Answer (score 3):

It's not available in the Python API, but you can call `isLocal` on the Java SparkContext as:

```
sc._jsc.isLocal()
```